# Translation of a C for loop to Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
int i, n=3;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  printf("i = %d\n", i);
  i = 3
}
```

I know that it will go through the code 2 times. How do you translate this code to Ruby or how would this look like in Ruby? I have done some researcchh on it and since I am extremely new to Ruby I have no clue. The inside print part doesn't really matter I am more worried about how to set it up.

Comment: That code won't compile in C. Regardless, ruby has a for loop, but it's not used. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/1159/iteration#t=201611012034506435448).

Comment: I will check it out thanks

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Quick selections can discourage other answers and short-circuit members who are still preparing answers. There's no rush. Most here wait a minimum of a couple of hours.

Comment: I am new to this site and I am unfamiliar with how things go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a translation into Ruby of your code.

```
n = 3
i = 1
while i <= n
  puts "i = #{i}"
  i = 3
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I will try this out and see if it works

Comment: It is not a *literal* translation, since it does not increment `i`, whilst the C code does.

Comment: What does #{i} mean?

Comment: #{i} is a string interpolation.  it just prints the value of our i variable.

Answer (score 0):

For loops don't work the same in Ruby, for loops in ruby take in a range. You are better of with a while loop

```
i=0
n=3
while i<=n do
 puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
 i=3
end
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm has more details

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the never used `upto`

```
i = 0
n = 3
i.upto(n) do |ans|
  puts "Value of i is #{ans}"
end
```

or

```
n = 3
1.upto(n) do |i|
  puts "Value of i is #{i}"
end
```